# How do I show only the intrinsic color of 3D polygons?

Tags: graphics3d, color, polyhedra

System: Mathematica 9, Windows 7.

I want to assign a polygon a color in such a way that it is rendered in that color irrespective of any ambient light sources. In other words I want Yellow to be Yellow no matter whether it gets rotated to the top, left, right, front ...

I once figured out how to do this in version 3, when I produced functions to work on a Rubik cube (when it is kinda essential that lightsources won't distort the colors). IIRC I was to turn Lighting -> None, and Shading -> True. But that does not work with version 9. For example Lighting -> None gives all black. Lighting->"Neutral" was a bit better, but still produces like different GreyLevels. F1 gives me scores of nice looking examples of achieving neat effects, but, infuriatingly, **no way of deciding on the colors myself**. Surely one exists, but I just couldn't coerce on-line help to tell me how, because I don't know the correct buzzword.

Comment: maybe [Glow](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Glow.html)?

Comment: Thank you, @kguler. Setting Lighting->None, and replacing, for example, Red with the Glow[Red] in the Polygon specification does exactly this! Do you mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: just posted an answer using that combination.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I wasn't sure what "irrespective of any ambient light sources" meant -- in particular, whether you were referring specifically to the technical `Lighting` specification `"Ambient"`.  It seemed from your subsequent trials that you were searching for a solution using `Lighting`.

Comment: @MichaelE2:  Not sure about terminology. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using @MichaelE2's example, a combination of `Glow` and `Lighting->None` produces a similar picture:

```
Show[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"] /. 
  Polygon[p_] :> MapIndexed[{Glow[Hue[Mod[3*First[#2], 20]/20]], Polygon[#1]} &, p],
  Lighting -> None]
```

[image]

Alternatively:

> A surface can be specified as having an absolute color *col* by giving the combination of directives `Glow[col]`, `Black`, and `Specularity[0]`.  ([see: Glow >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Glow.html))

```
Show[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"] /. 
  Polygon[p_] :>  MapIndexed[{Glow[Hue[Mod[3*First[#2], 20]/20]], Black, Polygon[#1]} &, p]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps `Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}`?

```
Show[
 PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"] /. 
  Polygon[p_] :> 
   MapIndexed[{Hue[Mod[3*First[#2], 20]/20], Polygon[#1]} &, p],
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]